# It's suggested that he work hard. It's suggested that he works hard

Tags: grammar, differences, subjunctive-mood

It's suggested that he work hard.lt's suggested that he works hard. 
Which one is correct? 
I think,  It is suggested that he works hard. This is correct one. 
But,  how ? I am confused. 
Please clear them.

Answer (score 0):

It's suggested that he work hard. - Correct.

After the use of some verbs such as *suggest, demand, insist*, etc., which imply an obligation, followed by "that", the verb in the object clause usually takes the *subjunctive*, which is "work" in this case.

It may also be useful to know that (some) British speakers might not follow this rule.

Comment: Different people have different thoughts. I am confused yet.

Comment: After the use of some verbs such as suggest, demand, insist, etc., which imply an obligation, followed by "that", the subjunctive mood for the verb in the object clause ( "work" in this case) **may be chosen** . People in the US seem more prone to make this choice.

Comment: @user124234: I see why there could be some confusion. This certainly is a grey area. The sentence can also be re-phrased as "It's suggested that he should work hard." As Edwin Ashworth points out above, the use of 'infinitive' is acceptable as well.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth: The language and its rules governing the "Subjunctive mood" took their origin in the UK. If the speakers of UK do not follow them,  and allow variations, what would that be called? Your statement, "People in the US seem more prone to make this choice." implies that people in the UK aren't inclined to use "subjunctive" in similar contexts anymore. Any valid reasons why they do so? - Your thoughts are welcome.

Comment: (1) Progress? (2) Even the decline in use of the mandative subjunctive has been discussed here before. There is a school saying that, for instance, 'He insisted that Bob come'  is unambiguous and therefore to be preferred over  'He insisted that Bob comes'. But if one is to be consistent, one should ditch both and use the periphrastic construction with the modal should: 'He insisted that the Smiths come' (mandative subjunctive) is itself ambiguous, whereas 'He insisted that the Smiths should come' isn't, in spoken English.

Comment: Thanks. You ended it saying, "...in spoken English." Would it be different otherwise?

Comment: Modals have various meanings. 'He insisted that the Smiths should come' (unstressed) = 'He insisted that the Smiths come / came' (wouldn't accept their non-attendance). Stressed  'He _insisted_ that the Smiths _should_ come' = 'He was adamant that the Smiths had a moral responsibility to come'.